# OS System deselects from active window/How do I tell which app stole my focus in OS?

Tags: mac, macos-sonoma

When using and typing in Safari, email, messages, word, notes, WhatsApp etc the computer keeps unselecting the currently using app. I can't even remain in Split Screen Mode, cause it would auto deselect from Split Screen and go into the Desktop page. Happened after it was updated last night.

What I've done so far:

1. Not the trackpad issue
2. I don't use CleanMyMac, Cox, Razer apps. (many victims had these and uninstalled, worked out for them)
3. Restarted a billion times

Links from similar problems that others had:
Link 1: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253939032?sortBy=best
Link 2: [How do I tell which app stole my focus in OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/734007/how-do-i-tell-which-app-stole-my-focus-in-os-x/1822565?noredirect=1#comment2868821_1822565)

According to [Link 2](https://superuser.com/questions/734007/how-do-i-tell-which-app-stole-my-focus-in-os-x) , I've copy pasted all the codes in but i couldn't get the last part (step 3) right, it says no such file/directory. I've already did his step 1 and 2, had to do an update installation on step 2.

[SCreenshot of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HAap.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried starting in safe mode? You don't mention the OS version and Mac model but for pre-apple silicon Intel Macs hold shift at startup. for Apple Silicon Macs you hold the power button (I think...) to access a menu that allows safe boot. This will disable all but a handful of Apple services allowing you to narrow down the culprit.